# Is there a way in TeXstudio to mark an area in code for later consideration?

Tags: latex

In eclipse a `//TODO` marks an area in code as a task for later consideration.

Is there something similar in TeXstudio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible approaches for your problem:

1. If you import the package `todonotes` using `\usepackage(todonotes)` you can use the `\todo{text}`command. The text inside the todo command will appear in the structure-view, as green text in the editor and also as box in your document. You can also type `\listoftodos` which will print all your todos as a nice styled list. If you don't want it to appear it in your document use 2.
2. As you do in Eclipse just type `%TODO` followed by your text. It will then appear in the structure-view and also as green text in your editor.

Example:

```
\usepackage(todonotes)
\begin{document}
\listoftodos
\newpage
The scent coming from the kitchen \todo{Check spelling} was heavenly.
\end{document}
```

[image: Todo-List]
[image: Todo]

Comment: works like a charm, the only thing that I am missing (refering to Java) are the tags on the scrollbar with which you can directly jump into your TODOs.

Comment: @speziFish I dont thinkt that it's possible in TexStudio